# Sharepoint list upgrade behaviour

Tags: list, sharepoint, upgrade

I am wondering what is the best approach for upgrading existing sharepoint lists. For example I would like to add/remove some columns. What will happen with existing data? Let's consider two cases: 
1. creating list declaratively in xaml
2. creating list programmatically in code (e.g. feature activated)
Any differences in these approaches when upgrading a list?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience the best approach is to upgrade existing lists programmatically.
You can do that from feature event receiver on feature upgrading or from powershell script or .NET console application running on the server.

I prefer .NET console application because it is strongly typed and I have more control on how upgrade goes compared to feature event receiver.

To keep existing data you need to add new column to the list, move your data to new column, delete old column.

The way you upgrade list does not depend on how the list was created: programmatically or declaratively